# @Url.Content doesnt resolve absolute path on one server but does on another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

We currently have two different servers on same domain. But one server resolves

> @Url.Content("~/api/User")'

as

> http://domain.com/virtualdirectory/api/User

where as other server doesnt resolve it absolutely; rather it resolves it relatively like

> api/user

The code base is same and we are using MVC4. I am not sure as to where we went wrong or if there is any IIS/DNS settings that need to be done in order to get this fixed.

All help is appreciated; thanks :)

Comment: Although the docs say that this generates an absolute path, it lloks like the internal implementation returns a url which works fine in the client side (it calls `PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl`). Is your second app installed in the root of the server or in a virtual directory?

Comment: Both are installed as application, their AppPool and permissions are all identical

Answer (score 2):

This is related with the IIS Rewriting module in your IIS web server that return the path to `http://domain.com/virtualdirectory/api/User`

Take a look on the part of source code of @Url.Content below:

```
private static string GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, string contentPath)
{
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
     {
          return contentPath;
     }

     // can't call VirtualPathUtility.IsAppRelative since it throws on some inputs
     bool isAppRelative = contentPath[0] == '~';
     if (isAppRelative)
     {
           string absoluteContentPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(contentPath, httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
           return GenerateClientUrlInternal(httpContext, absoluteContentPath);
     }

     // we only want to manipulate the path if URL rewriting is active for this request, else we risk breaking the generated URL
     bool wasRequestRewritten = _urlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(httpContext);
     if (!wasRequestRewritten)
     {
            return contentPath;
     }

     // Since the rawUrl represents what the user sees in his browser, it is what we want to use as the base
     // of our absolute paths. For example, consider mysite.example.com/foo, which is internally
     // rewritten to content.example.com/mysite/foo. When we want to generate a link to ~/bar, we want to
     // base it from / instead of /foo, otherwise the user ends up seeing mysite.example.com/foo/bar,
     // which is incorrect.
     string relativeUrlToDestination = MakeRelative(httpContext.Request.Path, contentPath);
     string absoluteUrlToDestination = MakeAbsolute(httpContext.Request.RawUrl, relativeUrlToDestination);
     return absoluteUrlToDestination;
}
```

Use the codes below to check whether your web servers are having the URL rewritten:

```
bool requestWasRewritten = (httpWorkerRequest != null && httpWorkerRequest.GetServerVariable("IIS_WasUrlRewritten") != null);
```

And Also:

```
private volatile bool _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnCalculated = false;
        private bool _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnValue;
        private object _lockObject = new object();
        private bool IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            // Need to do double-check locking because a single instance of this class is shared in the entire app domain (see PathHelpers)
            if (!_urlRewriterIsTurnedOnCalculated)
            {
                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    if (!_urlRewriterIsTurnedOnCalculated)
                    {
                        HttpWorkerRequest httpWorkerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)httpContext.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
                        //bool urlRewriterIsEnabled = (httpWorkerRequest != null && httpWorkerRequest.GetServerVariable(UrlRewriterEnabledServerVar) != null);
                        bool urlRewriterIsEnabled = (httpWorkerRequest != null && httpWorkerRequest.GetServerVariable("IIS_UrlRewriteModule") != null);

                        _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnValue = urlRewriterIsEnabled;
                        _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnCalculated = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return _urlRewriterIsTurnedOnValue;
        }
```

> In summary, If both requestWasRewritten and IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn
>   return true, that means one of your web server has IIS Rewrite Module
>   turned on and running while the other one doesn't have.

For more details on ASP.NET MVC source codes, please refer to this link:

```
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/
```

Hope it helps!